# Unable to run LaTeX from C++ system() function

Tags: c++

I would like to compile a LaTeX source from a C++ program (I’m working with Xcode). The shell command is `xelatex` (XeLaTeX is the variant I use) and could not be easier. Here is the syntax:

```
xelatex file.tex
```

This works like a charm. I use this command several times per day.

However, the following C++ line

```
system("xelatex file.tex");
```

returns an error message stating that the command does not exist (`sh: xelatex: command not found`to be precise). Any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the reason is that the directory where `xelatex` resides isn't in the `$PATH` value.

To be sure, use the full paths; something like

```
system("/home/zozor/something/xelatex /home/zozor/somethig_else/file.tex");
```

If `xelatex` and `file.tex` are in the same directory where you run the C++ program, you can try (but I suggest to try before with the full path)

```
system("./xelatex file.tex");
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English